# How to select precisely a code block in String (Methods, Functions)

Tags: c#, string

I have a code in String and I need to select only the method that I want, for example:

```
        "public void GetEntities(List<PublisherBO> _publishers, WebResourceBO _webResourceBO, SqlBO _sqlBO) {

            List<EntityBO> entities = new List<EntityBO>();

                List<EntityMetadata> results = entityDAO.GetAllEntities();
                EntitiesMetadata = results;
                entities = ConvertEntities(results);

            Data = entities;
        }

    public void ResetConnection() {
        sqlOpen = false;
        dynamicsOpen = false;

        if (Service != null) {

            if (Service.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null)
                Service.OrganizationWebProxyClient.Close();

            Service.Dispose();
        }
    }"
```

And I want to select only this:

```
"public void ResetConnection() {
            sqlOpen = false;
            dynamicsOpen = false;

            if (Service != null) {

                if (Service.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null)
                    Service.OrganizationWebProxyClient.Close();

                Service.Dispose();
            }
        }"
```

I know that I have to use IndexOf Methods, the complicated is consider the `{ }` because I know that I need to finish the select on code in `}` but how to consider the others `{ }` inside this block of code and precisely select all method.

And a note: I cannot divide this in lines, because some codes have only 1 line (javascript)

Comment: _"I have a code in String"_ Sorry, but already the first sentence let me stop reading. What real problem are you trying to solve here? It seems this is just another [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: It sounds like you want to parse C#.  Is that correct?  If so, look at Roslyn or Antlr.  You won't be able to do it using any simple mechanism like IndexOf or Regex

Comment: Briefly, select a complete block of code after a method or function, the regex code of @bhmahler works well to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regex pattern that will work to match code blocks.  It can fail if there are unclosed {} inside of strings.

```
(.*?){(?:[^{}]+|{(?<n>)|}(?<-n>))+(?(n)(?!))*}
```

[Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.*%3F%29%7B%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2B%7C%7B%28%3F%3Cn%3E%29%7C%7D%28%3F%3C-n%3E%29%29%2B%28%3F%28n%29%28%3F!%29%29*%7D&i=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20void%20GetEntities%28List%3CPublisherBO%3E%20_publishers%2C%20WebResourceBO%20_webResourceBO%2C%20SqlBO%20_sqlBO%29%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20List%3CEntityBO%3E%20entities%20%3D%20new%20List%3CEntityBO%3E%28%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20List%3CEntityMetadata%3E%20results%20%3D%20entityDAO.GetAllEntities%28%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20EntitiesMetadata%20%3D%20results%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20entities%20%3D%20ConvertEntities%28results%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Data%20%3D%20entities%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20void%20ResetConnection%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sqlOpen%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dynamicsOpen%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28Service%20!%3D%20null%29%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28Service.OrganizationWebProxyClient%20!%3D%20null%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Service.OrganizationWebProxyClient.Close%28%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Service.Dispose%28%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D&o=i)

Here is a working example in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var text = @"public void GetEntities(List<PublisherBO> _publishers, WebResourceBO _webResourceBO, SqlBO _sqlBO) {

                                List<EntityBO> entities = new List<EntityBO>();

                                    List<EntityMetadata> results = entityDAO.GetAllEntities();
                                    EntitiesMetadata = results;
                                    entities = ConvertEntities(results);

                                Data = entities;
                            }

                        public void ResetConnection() {
                            sqlOpen = false;
                            dynamicsOpen = false;

                            if (Service != null) {

                                if (Service.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null)
                                    Service.OrganizationWebProxyClient.Close();

                                Service.Dispose();
                            }
                        }";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(text, "(.*?){(?:[^{}]+|{(?<n>)|}(?<-n>))+(?(n)(?!))*}");
            if (matches.Count > 0)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a link to regex storm showing the original pattern matching C# code as well as JS code with various syntax
[Regex Storm with C# and JS](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.*%3F%29%7B%28%3F%3A%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2B%7C%7B%28%3F%3Cn%3E%29%7C%7D%28%3F%3C-n%3E%29%29%2B%28%3F%28n%29%28%3F!%29%29*%7D&i=public%20void%20GetEntities%28List%3CPublisherBO%3E%20_publishers%2C%20WebResourceBO%20_webResourceBO%2C%20SqlBO%20_sqlBO%29%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20List%3CEntityBO%3E%20entities%20%3D%20new%20List%3CEntityBO%3E%28%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20List%3CEntityMetadata%3E%20results%20%3D%20entityDAO.GetAllEntities%28%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20EntitiesMetadata%20%3D%20results%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20entities%20%3D%20ConvertEntities%28results%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Data%20%3D%20entities%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20void%20ResetConnection%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sqlOpen%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dynamicsOpen%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28Service%20!%3D%20null%29%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20%28Service.OrganizationWebProxyClient%20!%3D%20null%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Service.OrganizationWebProxyClient.Close%28%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Service.Dispose%28%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getStuff%28%29%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20var%20x%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20getStuff%20%3D%20function%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20x%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20getStuff%20%3D%20%28e%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20var%20x%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: Ty, this regex is great, but in RegexR.com says that have a error in "?" but in Regex Storm works fine, I will test this in C# to see if this works well

Comment: This is a pattern for .net regex specifically since it does not support recursion.  It is slightly different for PCRE regex. With recursion support it would just be (.*?){(?:[^{}]+|(?R))*}

Comment: Well, I tested this on C# and is not working properly, the matches in the RegexStorm and C# are differents and when I put (function)(.*?){(?:[^{}]+|{(?<n>)|}(?<-n>))+(?(n)(?!))*} in Regex this works fine and in C# this not get matches.

Comment: Also, why are you adding (function)? that will not match any of the code you posted in the example.  The original regex should find any text on a line up to a { and then everything up o it's closing }

Comment: I found the problem, the code that i'm verifyng have a \n between the function and the {, so the Regex don't detect the line with the function, only after "{". I put the (function) because some codes have comments and the regex detect the comments + function + parameter + {, with (function) it will only select the function part and the code, but this not work when the { starts in a new line. But I will make a workaround to fix this.

Comment: As a side note, if you turn on the SingleLine option in you regex, it will match the { on the next line.