# MatchCollection.Count never ends

Tags: c#, regex, match

I'm facing a problem in a MatchCollection made by a Regex. When I use a .Count in this MatchCollection the processing never ends like it's prisioned in a infinite loop.

Technically the MatchCollection cannot calculate how many elements have in the List, then if I use this List in a foreach, this get stucked.

The Code is that:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(OriginalSource, "(function)(.*?){(?:[^{}]+|{(?<n>)|}(?<-n>))+(?(n)(?!))*}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var ssc = 0;

try {
ssc = matches.Count;
} catch (Exception ex) {
throw new Exception("LOL");
}

foreach (Match match in matches) {
// ...
}
```

The string OriginalSource is that: https://pastebin.com/UcL710g7?fbclid=IwAR1HNXZpkxo76Ecxdib9XgaBu0Rz2YmJsRoKFOmrPvLYjQkyY3nKl8RSbgI

How can I deal with it? This not have a Exception, It's possible to create a Time out process? Because I can ignore this code, but this List don't let me move foward.

Comment: How large is your source, have you tried the regex with a program like expresso?

Comment: Regex Storm returns Time Out, Visual Studio debugger using the immediate window returns Time out, but running this never get a time out

Comment: Calling `Count` will use direct evaluation, meaning all matches will be collected. This can cause a great performance hit. Looping over the collection will use lazy evaluation, so you should see less of a performance impact, unless finding the first match takes a long time. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Why don't you use an atomic group to prevent too much backtracking? Are you in control of the regex? Try `(function)(.*?){(?>[^{}]+|{(?<n>)|}(?<-n>))+(?(n)(?!)|)}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's possible to create a Time out process?

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(OriginalSource,
     "(function)(.*?){(?:[^{}]+|{(?<n>)|}(?<-n>))+(?(n)(?!))*}", 
     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
```

adds a timeout (and the timeout works). This was added in .NET 4.5.

Comment: I'm using NET 3.5.2 :(

Comment: @Forsaiken that's ... inconvenient :(

Comment: This proves that Regex.Matches don't calculate the matches in this command, only calculate when the List is used, this is so wrong ._.

Answer (score 0):

There a mistake in your regex, it uses greedy quantifies. 
This leads to excessive backtracking.

I tried changing the regex to use `non greedy quantifiers`, now it takes `less than a second`.

Here's the regex:

```
@"(function)(.*?){(?:[^{}]+|{(?<n>)|}(?<-n>))+?(?(n)(?!))*?}"
```

It excactly like your except it uses non greedy quantifiers.

You can test the C# regex here: http://bak-o-soft.dk/RegEx/RegExBuilder.aspx

Comment: Your Regex don't select correctly the block of code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840091/how-to-select-precisely-a-code-block-in-string-methods-functions

Comment: This have to quantify { and } to know when the main block closes and select the match correctly

Comment: You haven't told us what your regex should match, so I just used it as it was.